# "Indentation size" disabled in Eclipse XML plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I edit XML files in eclipse, I want tabs to be 4 spaces. I know where to go to change this, but the option is disabled. See the attached screenshot.

[image]

How do I make it let me set that to 4?

Answer (score 8):

You can make it simple: set cursor left of the number and scroll the wheel =) It works. Checked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux or Mac, try
eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2

It could be a GTK 3 bug.

In any case, you can edit .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.prefs and place indentationSize=4 there. Better to do so when Eclipse is closed.